Issues running DeepFace python library in Touchdesigner
Hi i've got some issues using DeepFace python library in touchdesigner,  i've installed python 3.11 and other packages realted  like pandas,tensorflow,numpy to make DeepFace work properly on my MacOs arm64.
I tried to import DeepFace analysis into my mac terminal and it works.
But when i try to do the same in thing in touchdesigner i got this error, seems like he is still referring to a numpy for windows environment, idk why this happen it is related to touchdesigner built-in python.
Here you can see deepface working in my Mac terminal:
Python 3.11.1 (v3.11.1:a7a450f84a, Dec  6 2022, 15:24:06) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

from deepface import DeepFace
img_path = "/Users/enricoscigliuto/Downloads/testimg.jpg"
actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion']

try:
   objs = DeepFace.analyze(
   img_path=img_path,`
   actions=actions
)
print("Risultati:", objs)
 except Exception as e:
 print("Errore:", str(e))`
Action: emotion: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4/4 [00:01<00:00,  3.37it/s]
Risultati: [{'age': 30, 'region': {'x': 363, 'y': 0, 'w': 958, 'h': 958, 'left_eye': None, 'right_eye': None}, 'face_confidence': 0.95, 'gender': {'Woman': 99.94717240333557, 'Man': 0.0528238364495337}, 'dominant_gender': 'Woman', 'race': {'asian': 6.768146693398627e-05, 'indian': 5.2544646098675135e-05, 'black': 2.001801374727179e-07, 'white': 99.64854721444283, 'middle eastern': 0.19823610747771173, 'latino hispanic': 0.15308962241236895}, 'dominant_race': 'white', 'emotion': {'angry': 4.8653320261493604e-08, 'disgust': 1.9285744105814667e-15, 'fear': 3.196976017250108e-08, 'happy': 98.80461692810059, 'sad': 1.3317081659636187e-06, 'surprise': 0.010298862616764382, 'neutral': 1.185084

and this is the error i got into touchdesigner terminal:
python >>> from deepface import DeepFace
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/MacOS/TouchInit.py", line 184, in tdcustomimport
    r = previousimport(*args, **kw)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/MacOS/TouchInit.py", line 184, in tdcustomimport
    r = previousimport(*args, **kw)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/MacOS/TouchDesigner"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Textport>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/MacOS/TouchInit.py", line 184, in tdcustomimport
    r = previousimport(*args, **kw)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/DeepFace.py", line 13, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/MacOS/TouchInit.py", line 184, in tdcustomimport
    r = previousimport(*args, **kw)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/TouchDesigner.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) from e
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
python >>> 

